# Burninate the [percentage] tag and its friends

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Stack Overflow has tags for both [percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percent) (**Edit**: this is now burned) and [percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percentage) (<strike>893</strike> <s>973</s> 1089 questions). I think that either one, although probably [percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percent) since it is used less, should be burninated or *at least* made a synonym for the other. But since I don't have a score of 5 in either tag I am unable to do so myself.

What do you think?

**EDIT**:

I just started burning them, but I noticed another tag, [percentile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/percentile), as well. Should this tag be burned or left? It seems to deal with statistics and I'm okay with leaving it personally.

Comment: Some questions have both `[percent]` and `[percentage]` tags, for clarity I guess.

Comment: I agree 110% with you.

Comment: i think they both should go.

Comment: Make that 193 questions tagged with [tag:percent]. Most of the questions with this tag look like they'll require pretty extensive editing or a close vote. I'm already burned out ;P

Comment: Well, you guys should ask [Dalmas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/533552/dalmas?tab=tags&sort=name&page=5), I think.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer when nothing has actually been burninated?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was not familiar with how burninating works :P

Answer (score 46):

Both useless. Burninate both of them! They don't help with categorization.

I like fire. As long as I'm not in them.

Comment: Well, you could say that a single question per language could be categorized: "How to calculate a percentage in X". Just joking, burn all 100% of it.

Comment: *burn both 100%

Comment: What percentage of programmers are experts in percentages?

Comment: Approximately 1100100%

Comment: The `percent` tag has now been burned. We still need to do the `percentage` tag